# Specifying parameter type later and keeping the MVC naming convention

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, naming-conventions

I am in a situation where i want to define the parameter type inside the method. But if i do something like this:

```
    public class UserModel
    {
        public string InputName { get; set; }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(object obj)
    {
        UserModel test = obj as UserModel;
        ViewBag.Test = test.InputName;

        return View();
    }
```

The naming convention, that there is supposed to be in my `obj` when posting a form, does not take place? I think.
I wanna do this, because the `obj` type is located elsewhere.
Can this be done somehow? Do I need to overwrite something?

Edit: - Another way of addressing my problem.

When you post a form in a MVC web application. You receive the data by declaring a parameter type in your ActionResult. And here a naming convention takes place right? But what if i don't know the parameter type right away? How can I declare the parameter type later inside the ActionResult method and get the naming convention to happen there?

Hope it makes sense, and sorry for my English!

---

Thank you for your suggestions! I found another way to approach my problem.
And now i am stuck here instead :)

[View to String from another controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8606752/view-to-string-from-another-controller)

Comment: Your English is very hard to understand, could you please rephrase your question?

Comment: not sure (and no time to test) you can try public ActionResult Index(dynamic obj)

Comment: dynamic did not work. #Yuiry i have tried to explain it in another wat now :)

Comment: @BjarkeCK I understand what you want... However mvc automagically tries to map based on the parameter names. Instead of an object, can't you define an interface?

Answer (score 1):

```
[HttpPost]
     public ActionResult Index(object obj)   
     {    
         UserModel test = new UserModel();
         TryUpdateModel(test);  
         ViewBag.Test = test.InputName;     
             return View();     
      }
```

Try this way.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing yourself a disservice by using MVC and *not* using strongly typed action parameters. If you have models for your `Index` action that are that disjoint, you should probably be using multiple controllers each with their own `Index` action. At the minimum, these should be separate actions in the same controller. Maybe you could handle the decision to call a specific action on the client side:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#myButton').click(function(e) {
            var url = "User/Index";
            data = { InputName: 'username' };
            if(someCondition) {
                url = "User/AnotherAction";
                data = { SomeOtherModelField: 'someOtherValue' };
            }

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'POST',
                data: data,
                success: function(e) {
                    alert('post succeeded');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

And your controller could look like:

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(UserModel model)
    {
        // do UserModel stuff
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AnotherAction(SomeOtherModel model)
    {
        // do SomeOtherModel stuff
        return View();
    }
}
```