# View to String from another controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

i have done as Vdex suggested here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5801502/973485
And used the `RenderPartialToString` method he found. And it works perfectly like this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult Test()
    {
        string t = ViewToString.RenderPartialToString("Index", null, ControllerContext);
        return Content(t);
    }
}
```

But if i want to render the Home > Index from another Controller, i get:

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: controllerContext
```

Like this:

```
public class FooController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string t = ViewToString.RenderPartialToString("Index", null, new HomeController().ControllerContext);
        return Content(t);
    }
}
```

Is there any way to pass a View from another Controller to a string? I have tried many different methods, and it all of them fails at the ControllerContext. Many thanks!

**Update: Why i need to do this:**

Imagine i have a website full of widgets, the amount of widgets on each page is dynamic, so i cannot hardcode them in my cshtml file. But in that file there are different areas defined where the widgets gets printet out. To print out these widget i have a list of IWidgetController wich contains alle the different Widgets available, and the interface sais that they need to containe a ActionResult for edit, new and view. example of widgets: CalenderController, NewsController, GalleryController and so on... So in those areas i need to print out the content of each of those Controllers. Now i could also load the URLHTML but i figured doing it from the inside would be faster... right?

Comment: if your just wanted to delivery the home page as the home page of foo/index then you can just return view with a path  /Home/Index unless im missing something here

Comment: Year, i am building a CMS system, and i have a Interface for all Widget Controllers. Wich i have a list of. And then the database desides wich Controllers are printent on the page, in the different areas.

Comment: can't you just do Html.RenderAction("_CalendarWidget", "Calendar") from your view ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
string t = ViewToString.RenderPartialToString("Index", null, this.ControllerContext);
```

Anyway, why do you need to convert to a string?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. this.ControllerContext works! But it's the wrong ControllerContext, it needs to be the ControllerContext from the HomeController.

Comment: I am building a Widget System for my CMS, where each Widget has it own Controller with ViewWidget, EditWidget And newWidget ActionResults.

Comment: @gdoron Exatyly! ;) But it does not work if i need the ControllerContext from a nother Controller